# Sizing a spark list

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm using spark `List`s and `PopupAnchor`s to build a drop down menu system, but I'm having trouble getting it to size reliably - the list always seems to want to take up 5 itemRenderers worth of space, but some of the menus I need to implement can be 3 or less items long. How can I have the list dynamically size to the number of elements in it, and no larger?

Comment: BTW, I have a reusable custom spark drop down menu with icons and its completely skinned if you want to borrow the source code send me a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fun one. You need to set the property on the VerticalLayout of the spark list.

Try this snippet:

```
(yourSparkList.layout as VerticalLayout).requestedRowCount = yourDataProvider.length;
```

This assumes you've got a list named yourSparkList and a dataprovider called yourDataProvider which is populating the list.

If your lists get long, you should set a MAXIMUM constant like so:

```
public static const MAXIMUM:int = 5;

if(yourDataProvider.length <= MAXIMUM){
    (yourSparkList.layout as VerticalLayout).requestedRowCount = yourDataProvider.length;
}else{
    (yourSparkList.layout as VerticalLayout).requestedRowCount = MAXIMUM;
}
```

BTW, there's also a requestedMaxRowCount and a requestedMinRowCount property.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the way you implemented it in your own menu?

Comment: I don't have it publicly available (yet) but soon hopefully. If you send me an email (contact on my website) I can email you the source code for what I've been working on.